# Conceptualising the physical environment in AI and videogame design

Tags: artificial-intelligence

This is a bit of a long shot but i'm currently working on a research project in psychology/public health. One of the aims of this project is to develop a typology/"conceptual map" of how things in the proximal environment (i.e. close to an individual or inside rooms) can be changed in order to alter behaviour (the project is centered around how the environment can be changed to promote healthy behaviours).

I was wondering whether there was anything in AI/computer science/video game design that deals with how to conceptualise physical space. Both in terms of helping human designers think about rendering physical environments or also how AI/robots are taught to recognise features of the physical environment would be of interest. If anyone could point me in the direction of good papers/books on these topics it would be real useful!

Thanks